# Firebase + OneSignal - Store PlayerId in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm building an Ionic 1 app with Firebase as remote DB and OneSignal to send notifications.

I would like to send device to device notifications (ex. when two user are chatting together and a new message arrives and that the app is in background).

Would you recommend to store the PlayerId (OneSignal id for users) in the Firebase DB? Do you see any security concern doing this?

Would you recommend any other way to identify and retrieve the recipient's PlayerId?

Comment: You can configure the security rules so that information is readable only by the users themselves: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: I see your point but just to clarify, I would like user A to be able to retrieve user B PlayerId in order to send the notification directly to him (not through segments)

Comment: Security rules can be based upon information in the database, so if you have some information stored that links player B to player A, you can use that to grant read permission to player B, too. There should be some examples in SO; search for Firebase security rules and groups or teams, etc.

Comment: I am familiar with the rules in Firebase. I just wanted to get confirmation that the concept of authorizing user A to access (and know) user B's PlayerId was ok and didn't show any security breach. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about the OneSignal IDs, but if sharing them is okay, it sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you know this by now, but yes, you can.

Just save it as a node under the Users information, and then add it to `include_player_ids`.

Comment: Yes indeed I know now, but thanks for answering though.